Data from the API is not an array
When I test with postman at endpoint ' localhost:8080/studySpace' I get json but when I use console.log(response.data) to see data I am getting HTML.Screenshot of Console Log
My desired result should show different spaces below Top Picks
HomePage.jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Flex, Box, Text, Image, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import HomeImage from '../assets/Image1.jpg';
import PlaceCard from '../components/cards/PlaceCard';
import { spaceClient } from '../api/SpaceClient';

const HomePage = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  const loadBooks = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await spaceClient.getAllStudySpaces();
      console.log(response);
      
      // Check if response.data is an array before setting state
      if (Array.isArray(response.data)) {
        setBooks(response.data);
      } else {
        console.error("Data from the API is not an array:", response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching books:", error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadBooks();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box bg="#ECE8CD" minH="100vh" p={4}>
    <Flex direction="column" align="center">
      <Box maxW="70%" className="blurryImageContainer" w="100%">
        <Image src={HomeImage} alt="HomeImage" className="blurryImage" w="100%" />
      </Box>
      
      <Box textAlign="center" my={4}>
        <Text fontSize="xl">Empowering your study journey — Reservify, where space meets efficiency!</Text>
      </Box>

      <Box textAlign="center" my={4}>
        <Text fontSize="2xl" fontWeight="bold">Top Picks</Text>
      </Box>

      <Flex direction="column" align="center" w="100%">
        {books.slice(0, 2).map(book => (
          <Box key={`studySpace-${book.spaceId}`} my={3} w="50%">
            <PlaceCard place={book} />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Flex>
      

      <Box textAlign="center" my={4}>
        <Text fontSize="lg">
          Reservify revolutionizes the way you secure study spaces! This brings a seamless and user-friendly experience to the process of reserving study rooms and collaborative areas within educational institutions in Tallinn. Whether you're a student, researcher, or professional, Reservify ensures you have instant access to the perfect study environment, enhancing productivity and fostering collaboration.
        </Text>
      </Box>

      <Box textAlign="center" my={4}>
        <Button colorScheme="blue" size="lg" as="a" href="/resevify/bookspace">Book space</Button>
      </Box>
    </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

SpaceClient.jsx
import axios from "axios";

const spaceClient = {

    getAllStudySpaces(){
        return axios.get("api/studySpace")
    },
    createspace(space){
        return axios.post("api/studySpace", space)
    },
    getStudySpaceById(spaceId) {
        console.log(`api/studySpace/${spaceId}`);
        return axios.get(`api/studySpace/${spaceId}`)
    },
}

export {spaceClient}

vite.config
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()], 
//   base: '/resevify/',
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
            },
        },
    },

})

I would appreciate if you could find what's the issue.
Also, When I uncomment the base in config, I get this.Screenshot After base is added

In the SpaceClient.jsx file, wrap the function with async/await to make it asynchronous and wait for the axios.get call to complete before returning the response data.
Exmaple:
async getAllStudySpaces(){
return await axios.get("api/studySpace")
},

Can you edit in the controller method(s)? Spring can give different reponses depending on GET/POST, or the MIME type, or if the user is authenticated

when you call axios try putting an / before the url like: axios.get("/api/studySpace")

Thank you very much This thing worked- axios.get("/api/studySpace")
